# Parsing a PDB file with multiple structures into an array

Tags: python, numpy, biopython, protein-database

I have a PDB file with a few thousand structures, and I would like to save the position coordinates of, say, the alpha carbons of the first ten structures into a numpy array. I can parse a PDB file with a single structure into an array using the code below, but cannot extend this to a file with many structures.

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
import numpy

pdb_filename ='./1fqy.pdb'
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1)
structure = parser.get_structure("1fqy", pdb_filename)
model = structure[0]
chain = model["A"]

S1coor = numpy.zeros(shape=(226, 3))
i = 0

for residue1 in chain:
     resnum = residue1.get_id()[1]
     atom1 = residue1['CA']
     S1coor[i] = atom1.get_coord()
     i = i + 1
```

Comment: 1FQY only has one structure & model. Is your file a concatenation of many PDB files? If so, why not just break them up into individual files?

Comment: Should I do that manually or is there a way I can incorporate that into the code?

Comment: Whichever you'd prefer. Can you provide any more information about this file? How exactly do you have thousands of structures in a single file?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pdb files, so I apologize in advance for sounding a bit unclear..I have a file that has information on each atom in a given structure, and there are around 10,000 structures in the ensemble.  For example, the first atom in the first structure has the following information:                       'ATOM      1  C   MET     1      20.383 -20.287   3.281  1.00  0.00           C'

Comment: There are then 1109 atoms in this structure.  After each atom in this structure, you have the exact same thing for another structure, and this repeats around 10,000 times.  Each structure is the same protein, but a different conformation.  I would just like to pull the 3 spatial coordinates of each alpha carbon in a given structure and store this in array.  I would like to do this for the first N>1 structures.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: So you have 10,000 .pdb files then, yes?

Comment: No, it is a single .pdb file with data from 10,000 different structures in it.

Comment: Well, the [PDB file format](http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html) is only meant to describe one structure. I'd advocate writing out each structure to its own file (perhaps use the `END` record as a delimiter?).

Comment: You can have multiple structures in one PDB, but each of them must have a different "chain" in the atom fields, and terminated with "TER". As "chain" is a single character field, the PDB file can only contain a low number of chains.

Answer (score 1):

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
import numpy , tempfile ,os , re

models_re = re.compile("MODEL")
pdb_re = re.compile(r"MODEL(.*?)ENDMDL", re.DOTALL)

def PDB_parse(pdb_file_handle):
    model_pos = []
    models = []
    k = open(pdb_file_handle,"r").read()
    for i in models_re.finditer(k):
        model_pos.append(i.start())
    for i in model_pos:
        models.append(pdb_re.search(k,i).group())
    return models

array_all_structure = []

for i in PDB_parse(pdb_file_handle):
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemproaryFile(delete = False)
    temp_file.write(i)
    temp_file.close
    structure = parser.get_structure("1fqy", temp_file.name)
    os.remove(temp_file.name)
    model = structure[0]
    chain = model["A"]
    S1coor = numpy.zeros(shape=(226, 3))
    i = 0
    for residue1 in chain:
       resnum = residue1.get_id()[1]
       atom1 = residue1['CA']
       S1coor[i] = atom1.get_coord()
       i = i + 1
       array_all_structure.append(i)
```

May be this kind of linker will help , where you first isolate pdb files and then read them accordingly.